# Twitter API - fetch hashtags by keywords

Tags: twitter

I want to fetch all the existing hashtags in twitter based on keywords in my java application.

e.g. If I pass keyword as 'FIFA World Cup 2014' it should give me list of all the hashtags related to FIFA world cup.

Is it possible to achieve this using Twitter's API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to achieve this using Twitter's API?

No - maybe, probably. Twitter's search API returns tweets based on hashtags/keywords, not hashtags. If you keep monitoring trending topics, maybe you can get some headway, but considering how easy it is trend things, I'd  stay away from this approach

Comment: Is there any other way using which I can get list of hashtags based on  keyword, programmatically.